# Forward Action UIButton in IBDesignable to Parent Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibutton

Lets assume that, i have a view hierarchy like below:

```
-- > UIViewController (myViewController)
---- > UIView (IBDesignable - myCustomView)
------- > UIButton (myButton)
```

Is there a possible way to tell `myViewController` that `myButton` has been triggered by user interaction, for example `.touchUpInside`, "**WITHOUT**" the *Delegate Pattern* using either `Swift` or `Objective C`?

Please note that `myCustomView` is an IBDesignable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the `UIButton` variable on your viewController using an `IBOutlet` for example.

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
```

Than you can just the target - action pattern. Just add this in your viewController.

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleButtonTouch(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and declare your function on the viewController

```
 func handleButtonTouch(_ button: UIButton) {
        print("button has been pressed")
 }
```

**EDIT**

You can also declare an `IBAction` function straight from the Interface Builder.

Click on your `UIButton` instance, hold down the `CTRL` key on the keyboard, and drag it to your `UIViewController` subclass.

Settable properties:

> ```
> Connection: Action
> Name: function name, something like `handleButtonTouch`
> Type: UIButton
> Event: the event you would like the function to be fired, in your case it is `Touch Up Inside`
> ```

[image]

Comment: @erdhee You should go with this solution instead of mine. Read your questions again an realised that the button is already in the viewcontroller, just connect it 

Comment: @ViktorGardart using the notification pattern is also a good solution ;)

Comment: I wouldn't use it in this case though :)

Comment: @dirtydanee is there any way to do this in IB (non-programatically to make a connection between UIButton and an Action in controller). I've never think that this should work in this case before, and i think this is the best solution so far.

Comment: sure, is your `myCustomView` part of `myViewController ` or is it in an independent xib?

Comment: @dirtydanee it's an independent XIB file. MyCustomView is not an UIView inside MyViewController.

Comment: in this case, you have to stick with setting it up programmatically.

Comment: @dirtydanee i hope next version of xcode can support this in IB. Anyway, thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

You could use notifications.

Add this code to where the button is pressed

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "ButtonTapped"), object: nil)
```

And this one in `myViewController`:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(methodToBeCalled), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "ButtonTapped"), object: nil)
```

Change "ButtonTapped" to whatever suits your need best, and also `methodToBeCalled` is the name of the method which should be executed.

Comment: i would recommend also to un observe the notification in the `UIViewController` sublclasses `deinit` function.

Comment: I don't think notification pattern works fine for this case. I think it's overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your `myButton` as a public property on your `myCustomView` and from code in your `myViewController` you can call this method

```
[myCustomView.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Don't forget to implement `myButtonPressed` method just like:

```
- (void)myButtonPressed:(UIButton*)aButton
{
    //Do something....
}
```